# AIX netstat -a proto column

Tags: aix, netstat

Greetings everyone,

I am looking at the output of the "netstat -an" output on an AIX 7 server and the proto column has confused me a little bit.  First, the output:

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp6       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0  *.111                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

I understand that the SSH server (TCP port 22) is listening on both IPv4 and IPv6.  But is portmap (TCP port 111) listening on IPv4, IPv6, or both?  Neither the AIX man page and what I can find on the IBM support site differentiate or define specifically what the "tcp" protocol means or includes (4/6/both).

Thank you for your help!

john

Comment: I'd start here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/communicationtechref/socket.html or here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/communicationtechref/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

If your socket is of address family AF_INET, then it is `tcp4` in `netstat`

```
netstat: tcp4       0      0  *.57312                *.*                    LISTEN
```

If your socket is of address family AF_INET6, then it depends on `IPV6_V6ONLY` option:

```
int v6only= 0;
setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &ipv6only, sizeof ipv6only);

netstat: tcp        0      0  *.57313                *.*                    LISTEN
```

if this option is set

```
int v6only= 1;
setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &ipv6only, sizeof ipv6only);

netstat: tcp6       0      0  *.57314                *.*                    LISTEN
```